# Native Library net.dll already loaded in another classloader

Tags: java, dll, java-native-interface, jna, loadlibrary

I have two third party dlls: Net.dll and API.dll. **API.dll depends on Net.dll**

When I use `System.loadLibrary("Net");` the program reports an error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library D:\Java\jdk1.8.0_311\jre\bin\net.dll already loaded in another classloader.

If I use the absolute path to load Net.dll, such as `System.load( "D:\\Net.dll");` and then use `System.load("D:\\API.dll");` the program reports an error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: D:/API.dll, Cannot find the specified program.

Is Net loaded by default in the system? Therefore, the API.dll cannot find the dependencies correctly? What should I do?

Comment: Yes, `net.dll` is part of the JRE and is already loaded.  Your commands for the second part don't match up. You load a library named `API` but the DLL appears to be named `CCardLibEx.dll` and you're referring to a different load command.  You're also using core Java loading commands, not JNA nor JNI.  Can you clarify exactly what you're loading and from which paths?

Comment: I re-edited the question, thanks